# Unable to modify registry on Windows IoT

Tags: powershell, registry, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I try to modify registry on Windows IoT Core 10 running over Raspberry Pi 3 via Power Shell, but I get this error:

> [192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\Users\administrator\Documents> reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost" /v Ethernet /d 2 /f
>
> reg.exe : ERROR: Access is denied.
>
> - CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (ERROR: Access is denied.:String) [], RemoteException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I run the command with administrator.

What can be the issue?

Comment: You won't be able to modify `DefaultMediaCost` registry as even Administrators have only "Read" access on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @Mudit Bahedia has pointed out you have not enough permission to write this DefaultMediaCost key. So the error is expected also on Desktop.

But on **desktop** you can change the values. You will need to [use RMB/Permissions/Advanced to change its owner to Administrators or your own username and then give said user Full Control.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-to-set-an-ethernet-connection-as-metered-to/ecdaca08-d413-4a6a-9e33-b4afb337fc18) Or use the following UI setting:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to edit this key on **Windows IoT Core**.

You can submit a feedback about this feature.

Comment: Thanx for so detailed answer.